# Replaying file system calls

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a collection of file system I/O calls of the format

```
processid   system-call
```

For example

```
1  open(A)
1  read(A)
2  open(B)
1  open(C)
2  write(B)
.....
```

i.e interleaved sequence. I now need to replay these traces in approximately the same order and each process being executed by a different thread. In the program i have written, the main thread reads the trace file and allocates task to the thread corresponding to the process by putting the system call in the task queue of the concerned thread. The task thread reads calls from its queue and makes the necessary calls.

But I am not achieving the interleaving as seen in the I/O trace file. Please suggest me a way...

Thank you

Edit: One way is to delay the reading of the file by main thread after each trace is called thus allowing the task threads to proceed. This makes the purpose of  threads useless but it seems to serve my purpose

Comment: any reason you use multiple threads ? easiest way would be to replay the calls in one thread so you have the same order... IF that is not possible you will need to coordinate the threads i.e. make one thread wait until another thread executed a specific command before it continues...

Comment: You are subject to the vagaries of scheduler.  What's your real objective?

Comment: @Yahin Using multiple threads is due to back compatibility to a next part of the program that i wrote quite sometime ago. It would be a huge task for me to change it now. So trying to find a way around it

Comment: @Duck...yes, I agree with you. Actually I am studying the effect of concurrency(a part of a much larger project) and the same system call trace needs to be run several times.

Comment: But the call trace was from multiple processes (multiple cores?) and now you want to play them back as threads in one process?  Presumably some of the calls of PIDs 1 and 2 were run concurrently and others were not?  Is that distinction important?

Comment: @Duck yes..my project requires it

Comment: Well it is an interesting problem but I don't see an easy solution.  With hyper-precise timestamps from the trace you might approximate alternating between threads with some clever use of condition variables and the like but I don't know of any way to force two threads to run at once.

Answer (score 0):

Have the dispatcher go to sleep after it tells the thread what to do and sleep until it is woken up by the thread when the thread completes. You won't have simultaneous execution; you will have ordered execution by different threads. That's what you have asked for, but it's probably not what you want. What you probably want is a dependency graph written into the file and to have each thread wait until its dependencies are completed. Some languages (like prologue and haskell) will do this for you.